# how to place a browse button in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on my first project in PHP. I have a form in HTML in which i have a field image. Now I want to browse from my computer and select an image and send it to my table in mysql database using php. For this I need to have a browse button beside the textbox. My html code is:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">Image</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="image" style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" size="20" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['image'])) print $_POST['image']; ?>" maxlength="50" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please tell me how to place the browse button .

Comment: My goodness... Did you do any searching before asking this question (or make any other effort)? [Google search: html browse for file](https://www.google.com/#q=html+browse+for+file).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this

`<input type="file" name="image" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think u need something like this

`<td><input type="file" name="imagename"></td>`

Comment: Without given a name, we cant get that on server side

Comment: @ranjith yes I get it

Answer (score 0):

You need to `input` type as `file` also build with `multipart form-data` to send a image

```
<form action="your_action_page"
  method="Your_action_method" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="file" name="imageName"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: why do we need the multipart/form-data part?

Comment: @user3513993 Normally, we can't send a `image` like text on the `server` side. This will encrypt your image when `POST` method called.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to select file or image from your pc to html page or browser
`<input type="file">`

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code

```
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Image</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="image" style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" size="20" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['image'])) echo $_POST['image']; ?>" maxlength="50" />\
    <input type="file" name="image" />

</td>
</tr>
```

`file` control is used to browse any file from local hardisc.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopaljoshi73/v68kT/)